# How do I draw a tree upside down in qtree?

Tags: qtree

How do I draw a tree upside down in `qtree`?

So root at the bottom and leaves at the top.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This cannot easily be done with **qtree**. However, it can be done with **tikz-qtree** and the syntax for specifying the trees is essentially identical, except for additions thanks to TikZ.

Page two in [the manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikz-qtree/tikz-qtree-manual.pdf) should solve your problem.

> The `grow=direction` and `grow'=direction` options control the orientation of trees just as for standard TikZ trees. However, direction must be one of `up`, `down`, `left`, or `right`. The difference between grow and `grow'` is that grow places children counterclockwise with respect to their parent and `grow'` places them clockwise:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow'=up]
            \Tree [.NP [.Adj upside-down ] [.N tree ] ]
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome! Make sure to mark your question as solved when this answer solved your problem.

Comment: It might help to mention @ZiWang like this to get attention from him. Otherwise he might not see your comment. BTW: nice answer (+1)

Comment: Just to be fair, `tikz-qtree` and `qtree` are different packages; you can't easily draw a tree upside down in regular `qtree`, so if Zi Wang was using the latter, he couldn't have found the answer in the manual.