# how can I draw this organization chart by using "forest"?

Tags: forest, charts

[image]

how can I draw this organization chart by using "forest"? or other methods?

Comment: Hi and welcome to TeX.SX. You could use `tikz` package. Take a look at examples such as this https://texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/forest/

Comment: Also this https://texample.net/tikz/examples/family-tree/ and this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52889/how-do-i-draw-a-tree-upside-down-in-qtree

Comment: thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames, table]{article}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\newcommand{\chartbox}[2]{\psDefBoxNodes{#1}{\fboxrule=0.8pt\fcolorbox{MediumBlue}{white}{%
\makebox[0.25\textwidth]{\rule[-3ex]{0pt}{8ex}\sffamily#2}}}}

\begin{document}

\centering
\hfill\chartbox{A}{A}\hfill\chartbox{B}{B}\hfill\chartbox{C}{C} \hfill\null\vskip 2cm

\chartbox{D}{D}
\psset{linewidth=1pt, linecolor=LightSteelBlue, linejoin=1, arrows=->, arrowinset=0.12}
\ncline{B:bC}{D:tC}
\psset{armB=1.1cm, angleA=-90, angleB=90}
\ncangle{A:bC}{D:tC}
\ncangle{C:bC}{D:tC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

[image]

This is simple diagram. You need to load forest with option `edges` (for forest library edges, which define forked edge) :

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={
% tyle of nodes
    draw = teal, semithick,
    font = \sffamily,
    text width = 18mm, text badly centered,% <-- "align=center" doesn't work
    inner sep = 3mm,
% style of tree (edges, distances, direction)
    parent anchor = north,
    parent anchor = north,
            grow' = north,
             edge = teal!50,
    forked edge,            % for forked edge
            s sep = 4mm,    % sibling distance
            l sep = 8mm,    % level distance
         fork sep = 4mm,    % distance from parent to branching point
         tier/.option=level,
               }
  [D        % root
    [A]     
    [B]     
    [C]     
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```